# Row updation on key press in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

gridview On Row Editing Event is fired, while pressing Enter Key on Textbox in Edit mode.

But my requirement is , update the row on  pressing the enter key.

How do to this in Server side?

I tried to set the default button to update button with in gridview. I cant set this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/gridviewenterkey.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1147765.aspx) out. Similar to what you want to achieve.